# python code(.py file) in Pycharm terminal opens in new window

Tags: pycharm

I git cloned a project from github and ran it with pycharm because its convenient.

The code needed be executed from terminal, like "python3 code.py".

so I go into terminal tab of Pycharm and input like below

```
.\code.py
```

this pops a new window (named ~~~\py.exe)

and executes itself and terminates. Termination of the program closes the window and I can't see the results.

How can I keep the terminal open to view the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pycharm was using Windows Powershell.

Therefore, Virtual Environment activated script cannot be executed because the execution policy was set to restricted.

**Changing the pycharm terminal setting to cmd** (from powershell) fixed the problem.